# What would be a good example of a community wiki question?

Tags: discussion, closing, questions, community-wiki

Since we are [discouraging list or open ended questions](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/should-we-welcome-via-community-wiki-useful-questions-that-dont-have-concrete-or) (rightly, I think), I am wondering what would CW be used for? What kinds of questions would be a good CW in this site, but will not be closed?

If there is none, why do we have the CW designation?

[Edit] Please also refer to the discussions elsewhere, like:

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/
- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)
- [Is Community Wiki still relevant?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14567/is-community-wiki-still-relevant)

Comment: I think there have been some pan-stack-exchange discussions on this topic which should be linked to this question before we can progress with an answer.

Comment: @hippie agreed. edited my question

Answer (score 3):

Please read [The Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/):

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly.
>
> [image: A really cheesy knife]
>
> Community wiki is for that rare gem of a post that needs true community collaboration. That’s when community wiki shines. If your site is teeming with community wiki posts — particularly in questions — you should consider the above points carefully.

Comment: Actually, I was asking for a specific example to this site. But thanks for the link

Comment: There aren't any. Y'all just ain't cuttin' the cheese enough!