# Are literature-search-type questions welcome or no?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Like a lot of academics, I'm way more narrowly specialized than is really convenient.  So a lot of the questions I'd be inclined to ask here would be of the form "Can anyone point me to research on X question from Y perspective?" — where Y is some subfield within linguistics that I'm not terribly familiar with.  Is this a legitimate use of the site?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the questions you have in mind? It can be a banal example, it doesn't matter, just to make us understand what you were thinking about. :)

Comment: @Dan do you mean questions like this? : http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/522/linguistic-research-on-translation-evaluation

Comment: also, if you want references in particular, I have been trying to popularize the [reference-request] tag

Comment: Louis Rhys -- Yes, that's the sort of thing I was thinking about when I posted this.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that is perfectly acceptable. It is about linguistics, and has a clear but arguable correct answer.

Comment: +1 I totally agree. This is pretty standard on most of the SE sites I participate in.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is acceptable as long as the scope is specific and unambiguous enough. Keep in mind we [decided](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/should-we-welcome-via-community-wiki-useful-questions-that-dont-have-concrete-or) to discourage open ended questions.